# Full node of bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core

I would like to have Bitcoin Core running as a full node. I thought it is like plus 100 GB. But on the web site it says it is no more than 20 GB. When I run Bitcoin-Qt is it enough to run full node or do I add any parameters before I start the program ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run bitcoin-qt the very first time just executing bitcoin-qt.exe (I assume you are windows user) and make changes later

Yes, there are some useful options. For example, I do not like that this program creates database on my disk [C:] under the \users\user...\folder

I like to keep my bitcoin database in D:\bitcoin

So, I have created file bitcoin.bat with the following contents:

---

```
start bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir=d:\bitcoin
```

---

There are other options, but I think that you will find them yourself later. Default options are quite good.

Comment: The question is : Do I have to do anything to be a full node other than running the bitcoin-qt ? 20 GB looks small

Comment: Current size of blockchain is 20+ gb. And there are index files. So, I think that it would be nice to leave at least 30-50 gb for bitcoin files. To be a full node you should run a program and synchronize you database with network.

Comment: It's a good idea to download the bootstrap torrent file first to get most of the 20 GB fast. Other than that you should be good to go. Make sure you forward the TCP port in your router so other people can connect to you, otherwise you're not really helping the network.